# warning Invalid next.config.js when running project - nextJs

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, config

When I want to run my project i have these three warnings:

```
1-
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected:  The root value has an unexpected property, webpack5, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

2-
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works

3-
warn  - ./node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

This is my `next.config.js`:

```
const {i18n} = require('./next-i18next.config')
const withVideos = require('next-videos')
module.exports = withVideos({
  reactStrictMode : true,
  i18n,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  },
})
```

I even tried this:

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
 const {i18n} = require('./next-i18next.config')
 const withVideos = require('next-videos')

 const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode : true,
  i18n,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = withVideos(nextConfig)
```

Result was same.

Comment: It seems like this `webpack5: true` is the problem. It should be absolutely there?

Comment: For the first warning, just remove `webpack5: true` from the config. For the other two warnings, you need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I hope so.

I had the same problem with the "autoComplete" from Google:

"The root value has an unexpected property, autoComplete, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, ..."

I wrapped it into an "env" object, like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  i18n: {
    ...
  },
  env: {
    ...
    autoComplete: {
      publicApiKey: '...',
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

And after restarting my app the warning was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**This is your primary next.config.js file**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true,
      
    }
        
    module.exports = nextConfig
```

**If you want to add some package to export, You should put your code into nextConfig variable. Like this:**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const path = require('path')

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I hope it will help you. For more details you can also read official documentation here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config